# C#. SQL Compact. Страницы индексации

Tags: c#, sqlce

Всем доброго времени суток. Так сложилось что в качестве СУБД использую SQL Server Compact. Собственно он удовлетворяет всем требованиям, но есть одна проблема. Файл базы данных, по специфике своей, перемещается между КПК и ПК. На КПК создается БД. Далее передается ПК. ПК наполняет его информацией и возвращает КПК обратно. Проблема в том что, при установке соединения с БД на КПК, после загрузки с ПК, начинается долгий этап пострaения таблиц индексации. Вопрос, как можно в коде заставить собраться страницы индексации еще когда БД находится на стороне ПК?

Comment: А не проще в такой ситуации перейти на обычный SQL Server?

Comment: не выйдет, так как приложение работает на КПК без сетевого доступа.